# Nested PreferenceFragmentCompat not displayed on Android 4.4

Tags: android, androidx, android-preferences

I recently refactored my Android app to use `PreferenceFragmentCompat` instead of the deprecated `PreferenceActivity` + `PreferenceFragment`.
The app uses a hierarchy of multiple preference screens.

I followed this article on the Android docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/organize-your-settings

This seemed to be working fine, until I noticed that under Android 4.4 the nested PreferenceFragments are not displayed - nothing at all happens when I click the Preferences on my main preferences screen.

There are no warnings and errors in the logs and according to the debug logs `onCreate` and `onResume` of the nested fragments are called.

I created [a minimum sample](https://github.com/ptreitler/androidx-preferences-sample) to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed the issue by replacing the `<fragment>` tag in the Activity that hosts my main PreferenceFragmentCompat with a `<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>`.

See [this commit](https://github.com/ptreitler/androidx-preferences-sample/commit/e0586aa7936ef4d354d508e95beb663fd6b64234) for details.

I'm not sure if that's a bug in the Android APIs or if I missed anything else.